# Parsing from a Text File

Tags: python, parsing

Can someone help me with this problem?

I have the following raw text file:

```
============================
Line of text
Line 3: Port #: 12; Type: 5000AX-FG;
============================

- - Stage 1 - -
Duration: 0 hrs 0.60 min.  Total Elapsed Time: 0 hrs 0.60 min.
Status: Done

...

- - Stage 8 - -
Line 66: Duration: 11 hrs 48.0 min.  Total Elapsed Time: 16 hrs 35.6 min.
Line 67: Status: Done
```

I want to parse the type (5000AX-FG), Duration of Stage 8, and Status of Stage 8.  My script will go through multiple files as well.  My problem is I am having a difficult time understanding how the regex module works in Python.  I'm having problems applying it to my situation.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import glob
import re
import csv

list_of_files = glob.glob('*06*.rpt')

for fileName in list_of_files:
    f=open(fileName, 'r')
    print f
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i == 2:
            print line
        elif i == 65:
            print line
        elif i == 66:
            print line
    f.close()
```

Comment: We're not a tutorial site. If you don't understand Regex there are plenty of tutorials available. Come back when you have a specific problem.

Comment: Parsing simple languages with plain string processing is a great way to get started… if for no other reason that eventually your code gets so frustrating that you finally have the motivation to sit down and learn regex or pyparsing or something better. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't understand regexps, and aren't willing to learn them, just don't use them. This is pretty easy to parse without them.

The first line you want to parse is:

```
"Line 3: Port #: 12; Type: 5000AX-FG;\n"
```

In English, what you want to do is:

- Strip the newline off the end of the line.
- Split the line into words, on each run of whitespace.
- Take the last word.
- Strip the semicolon off the end of it.

You can obviously rearrange these, combine some of them into one step, etc., but let's just translate this directly to Python:

```
if i == 2:
    line = line.rstrip() # 'Line 3: Port #: 12; Type: 5000AX-FG;'
    words = line.split() # ['Line', '3:', 'Port', '#:', '12;', 'Type:', '5000AX-FG;']
    last_word = line[-1] # '5000AX-FG;'
    part_type = last_word.rstrip(';') # '5000AX-FG'
    print part_type
```

---

If you want to be a little smarter, notice the patterns within the lines, and use them for splitting. For example, in this line, and all of the similar lines:

```
Line 66: Duration: 11 hrs 48.0 min.  Total Elapsed Time: 16 hrs 35.6 min.
```

They all start with `"Line NN: "`. After that, there are one or more key-value pairs, with the pairs separated by a period and optional whitespace, with a colon and optional whitespace separating each key and value. So:

- Strip off the trailing newline.
- Strip off the `"Line NN: "` part.
- Split on `'.'`
- For each component:

  - Split into exactly 2 pieces around the `:`.
  - Strip extraneous whitespace off the two pieces.
  - If the key matches the one you're looking for, the value is the one you want.

You can generalize it even further—make a dict of all of the key-value pairs, then you can just look up the one you want in that dict.

For example:

```
def parse_line(line):
    line = line.rstrip()
    line = line.partition(':')[-1]
    parts = line.split('.')
    mapping = {}
    for part in parts:
        key, _, value = part.partition(':')
        mapping[key.strip()] = value.strip()
    return mapping
```

Now:

```
if i == 65:
    mapping = parse_line(line)
    print mapping['Duration']
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
import glob

def parse_files(list_of_files):
    for fileName in list_of_files:
        with open(fileName, 'r') as f:
            f.readline()
            f.readline()
            line = f.readline()
            #"Line 3: Port #: 12; Type: 5000AX-FG;\n"
            yield line.split(';')[1].split(':')[1]

for result in parse_files(glob.glob('*06*.rpt')):
    print(result)
```